# Python получение индекса элемента произвольной глубины вложения

Tags: python, list

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли варианты получения индекса элемента при неизвестной глубине вложения, либо переменной которая указывала бы на путь к такому элементу?

Решаю задачу, где очень желательно делать изменения "на месте", хотя никто не запрещает подменять первоисточник на результат с изменениями.

Предположим у нас есть список:

```
lst = [
        'el1',
        ['el2', 15, 'text'],
        ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]],
        'el6'
     ]
```

Из этого списка мы хотим получить путь до элемента `'el5'` для преобразования его, к примеру, в кортеж.

Мои базовые знания python говорят, что мы можем создать временную переменную и, поиском перемещаясь по базовому списку, создать ссылку на интересующий элемент.

Могу ошибаться но при этом мы получим ссылку на тот локальный кусочек содержащий искомый элемент. Но для манипуляций Нам понадобиться ссылаться на источник с указанием полного пути индексами. В противном случае преобразования в первоисточнике не произойдут.

Можно получить путь, например в виде списка индексов по мере продвижения по первоисточнику:

```
def find_elem(lst: list, elem: any) -> list[int] | None:
    '''получаем путь до искомого элемента в виде списка индексов'''
    for i, el in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(el, (list, tuple)):
            returned = find_elem(el, elem)
            if returned != None:    #   проверяем был ли во вложенном списке искомый элемент
                return [i, ] + returned
        elif el == elem:
            return [i, ]
    return None #   элемент в переданной коллекции не нашелся


print(find_elem(lst, 'el5'))   #   вернет путь виде списка [2, 2, 1, 0]
```

Вопрос в том, как **этот список** преобразовать в
`needed_elem = lst[2][2][1][0]`

P.S. функцию писал на коленке просто что бы показать суть вопроса.

UPD. прилагаю результат применения алгоритмов с путешествием по первоисточнику и локализацией искомого элемента. В итоге первоисточник остается в первозданном виде...

```
needed_elem = find_elem(lst, 'text')   №   [1, 2]
needed_addr = lst[1][2]
needed_addr = ['text', 'new text']
print(lst)    #    ['el1', ['el2', 15, 'text'], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]], 'el6']

lst[1][2] = ['text', 'new text']
print(lst)    #    ['el1', ['el2', 15, ['text', 'new text']], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]], 'el6']
```

Как видно из приведенного примера, к изменениям привел только второй вариант обращения.

Comment: `''.join(f'[{x}]' for x in lst)` что-то такое

Comment: Простите не понял, что Вы имели ввиду. Вы предлагаете превратить список в строку? В таком случае не будет возможности изменения элемента списка. Можно только создать новый. В вопросе не указано - я пытаюсь решить задачу, где это вообще нужно(очень рекомендуется) делать «на месте»

Comment: Как вариант: можно собрать конструкцию в виде строки и ее передать в eval() - но это как мне кажется костыль из костылей…

Comment: зачем вам список преобразовывать в ``needed_elem = lst[2][2][1][0]``? Если вам нужно обратиться к указанному элементу, то ничего преобразовывать не надо. Сделайте еще одну функцию с циклом или рекурсией, которая постепенно будет обращаться к вложенным элементам.

Comment: Согласно теории: списки (в частности) хранят ссылки на значения. И применяя такой метод в итоге Мы получим копию ССЫЛКИ на значение. При попытке изменить неизменяемый тип данных (int, str, etc) - в новой переменной (после поиска) будет храниться ссылка на обновленное значение. В первоисточнике все останется по прежнему. (только что в Пайчарме проверил)

Comment: зачем вам новая переменная, если вы хотите изменить значение в исходном списке? Ну и сложно угадать, что вы там проверили, не имея кода.

Comment: создавайте новый список списков, в который будете помещать все элементы из старого рекурсивно, с заменой искомого элемента на нужный.

Comment: Применение временной переменной лишь предположение.  Я размышлял о возможности эдакой конструкции lst[index_value],  где применение index_value приведет в конечном итоге к реализации lst[x][y][z][q]...

Comment: "Могу ошибаться но при этом мы получим ссылку на тот локальный кусочек содержащий искомый элемент." - нет, вы получите ссылку на сам искомый элемент, а не на его место в списке. Перезапись значения в переменной приведет к изменению ссылки хранящейся в этой переменной, но не к изменению ссылки в исходном списке.

Comment: Согласен, выразился неправильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вопрос уже даны два правильных ответа. Добавить мне почти нечего кроме возможного дизайна для решения задачи.

Решений два. Первое - простое. Второе с синтаксическим сахаром.

### Простое решение

`locate(list_, value)` - генератор, который возвращает все вхождения значения `value` в список `list_`. Просматривается как сам список, так и все его подсписки, рекурсивно.

`replace_first(list_, old, new)` заменяет первое значение `old` (если оно есть) на `new`.

`replace_all(list_, old, new)` заменяет все значения `old` на `new`.

```
def locate(list_, value):
    for i, v in enumerate(list_):
        if v == value:
            yield list_, i
        if isinstance(v, list):
            yield from locate(v, value)


def replace_first(list_, old, new):
    for lst, i in locate(list_, old):
        lst[i] = new
        break


def replace_all(list_, old, new):
    for lst, i in locate(list_, old):
        lst[i] = new


lst = [
    'el1',
    ['el2', 15, 'text'],
    ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]],
    'el6'
]

print(*locate(lst, 'text'))

print(lst)
replace_all(lst, 'text', ['text', 'new text'])
print(lst)
```

> ```
> $ python replace.py
> (['el2', 15, 'text'], 2)
> ['el1', ['el2', 15, 'text'], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]], 'el6']
> ['el1', ['el2', 15, ['text', 'new text']], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]], 'el6']
> ```

### Решение с мультииндексом

Класс `NestedList` оборачивает список и предоставляет синтаксис вида:

> ```
> nlst = NestedList(lst)  # создание обёртки
>
> print(nlst[[1, 2]])     # обращение ко второму индексу
>                         # первого подсписка списка
>
> nlst[[1, 2]] = value    # изменение этого же элемента
>
> nlst.locate(value)      # перебирает все мультииндексы
>                         # значения value
> ```

```
class NestedList:
    def __init__(self, list_):
        self._list = list_

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        v = self._list
        for i in index:
            v = v[i]
        return v

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        v = self._list
        for i in index[:-1]:
            v = v[i]
        v[index[-1]] = value

    def locate(self, value):

        def locate(list_, stack):
            for i, v in enumerate(list_):
                top = stack, i
                if v == value:
                    index = []
                    node = top
                    while node is not None:
                        index.append(node[1])
                        node = node[0]
                    yield index[::-1]
                if isinstance(v, list):
                    yield from locate(v, top)

        yield from locate(self._list, None)



lst = [
    'el1',
    ['el2', 15, 'text'],
    ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]],
    'el6'
]

nlst = NestedList(lst)

print('list =', lst)
i = next(nlst.locate('text'))
print('i =', i)
print('nlst[i] =', nlst[i])
nlst[i] = ['text', 'new text']
print('nlst[i] =', nlst[i])
print('list =', lst)
```

> ```
> $ python replace.py
> list = ['el1', ['el2', 15, 'text'], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]], 'el6']
> i = [1, 2]
> nlst[i] = text
> nlst[i] = ['text', 'new text']
> list = ['el1', ['el2', 15, ['text', 'new text']], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]], 'el6']
> ```

Comment: Мне кажется, что ответа на вопрос основной все же нет. Есть решения, позволяющие изменять элементы вложенных списков в первоисточнике.. А вот ответа, как получить эдакую динамическую ссылку на интересующую переменную в привязке к источнику - нет. Я надеялся что кто то напишет некую синтаксическую сахарную вату типа   lst[#@$%&index]    - что приведет к развертыванию индексов всего пути...

Comment: Я могу добавить нужный синтаксис. Но будет ограничение: `lst` должен быть специального типа. просто список подставить не получится. Что-то вроде `MyLst(lst)[<indices>]. Годится?

Comment: Да Спасибо. Было бы как минимум интересно. В принципе при написании кода мы можем сами генерировать тип данных.

Comment: Уже сделано: `NestedList`.

Comment: Спасибо. Я после Вашего сообщения тоже задумался о реализации через класс.. Еще раз Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

создавайте новый список списков, в который будете помещать все элементы из старого рекурсивно, с заменой искомого элемента на нужный. вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72069888/8030503) для списка списков, с кортежами нужно будет допилить:

```
lst = [
        'el1',
        ['el2', 15, 'text'],
        ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]],
        'el6'
     ]

def replace_items(l, a, b):
    for i, item in enumerate(l):
        if (type(l[i]) == list):
            l[i] = replace_items(l[i], a=a, b=b)
        else:
            if l[i] == a:
                   l[i] = b
    return l

new = replace_items(lst, a='el5', b=0)
print(new)
```

> ['el1', ['el2', 15, 'text'], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', [0]]], 'el6']

*UPDATE*

Если вам просто интересно, как можно добраться до элемента, имея список вложенных индексов, то это реализуется так, например:

```
from functools import reduce 
from operator import getitem
lst = [
        'el1',
        ['el2', 15, 'text'],
        ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]],
        'el6'
     ]
idx = [2, 2, 1, 0]
res = reduce(getitem, idx, lst)
print(res)
```

> el5

Однако, мне не известны законные способы изменить значение таким образом для элементов списка.

*UPDATE 2*

Как тут справедливо подсказали, достаточно получить объект-самый вложенный список с искомым элементом и индекс этого элемента, тогда можно будет менять значения:

```
idx = [2, 2, 1, 0]
inner_lst = reduce(getitem, idx[:-1], lst)
inner_lst[idx[-1]] = "lol"
print(lst)
```

> ['el1', ['el2', 15, 'text'], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['lol']]], 'el6']

Comment: Это вариант достижения результата. Однако он не отвечает на вопрос: можно ли сделать эдакое динамическое обращение к коллекции, ее элементу.

Comment: я обновил ответ, с указанием кода, как получить искомый элемент.

Comment: Список индексов можно заменить на пару `(<самый вложенный список>, <индекс>)`. Этой пары достаточно чтобы читать и писать значение.

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы получаете элемент из списка (в том числе глубоко вложенного), вы действительно получаете ссылку, но ссылку не на место во вложенном списке, а на само значение. По этой ссылке нельзя заменить элемент в списке. Можно только мутировать объект (если он изменяемый), тогда его изменение отобразится в исходной структуре.

Чтобы изменить значение внутри вложенного списка, уже нужен сам список (вложенный список, где лежал элемент) и индекс в нем, т.е., условно, две "координаты". Тогда можно будет мутировать список, заменив значение по найденному индексу:

```
from typing import Any


def find_elem(lst: list, elem: Any) -> tuple[list, int] | None:
    for i, el in enumerate(lst):
        if el == elem:
            return lst, i
        elif isinstance(el, list):
            result = find_elem(el, elem)
            if result is not None:
                return result

    return None


lst = ['el1', ['el2', 15, 'text'], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]], 'el6']

position = find_elem(lst, 'el5')
assert position is not None, "Значение не найдено"

print(lst)
position[0][position[1]] = ['text', 'new text']
print(lst)

# Для лучшей читаемости строку position[0][position[1]] = ... можно переписать так
inner_list, i = position
inner_list[i] = ['text', 'new text']
```

Вывод:

```
['el1', ['el2', 15, 'text'], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', ['el5']]], 'el6']
['el1', ['el2', 15, 'text'], ['el3', '2.6', ['el4', [['text', 'new text']]]], 'el6']
```

Comment: Простите, мне кажется в строке      position[0][position[1]] = ['text', 'new text']    
 есть ошибка со скобками слева. Не могли бы Вы уточнить, что должна возвращать функция find_elem()

Comment: @AleksandrBogatyrev там нет ошибки

Comment: Добавил пример, как эту операцию более понятно можно расписать

Comment: "Не могли бы Вы уточнить, что должна возвращать функция find_elem()" - во втором абзаце написано. Возвращает вложенный список, в котором лежит искомый объект, и его индекс в этом списке. Ну или None, если объект не найден.

Comment: @AleksandrBogatyrev, берется второй элемент (элемент с индексом 1) из positon и подставляется как индекс.

Comment: Простите, это я не заметил открывающейся скобки. Мой косяк.

Comment: В случае Данного решения, Мы воздействуем не на элемент, а на содержащий его список. И в нем изменяем значение, а так как список уровнем выше содержит только ссылку на только что измененный список - изменения применяются к первоисточнику. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @AleksandrBogatyrev, примерно так